# What does shl( 5, ax ) do?

Tags: assembly, x86, hla

I'm using HLA, and don't understand this instruction:

```
shl( 5, ax )
```

I'd like detail on what this instruction is doing.

Comment: shl ... shift left 5 positions I guess ... without knowing assembly language ... but I was fast with my answer.

Comment: And my guess was right, now I found the time to google for: 'assembly language shl', and the result is: shl SHIFTS something (byte, word ...) number of bits LEFT.

Comment: nabuchodonossor - my guess for the down-vote was that the poster could've simply done what you did and looked it up themself.

Comment: CAbbott - the style of the question - e.g. ASAP, absence of PLEASE, encouraged me to give a FAST answer. And then, having a little spare time, I tried google search ... and I found, my guessing was right. I was happy about this, so I gave the second comment. The questioner seems to be young in this topic, I´m pretty sure he will grasp it; both topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This instruction means that the number in ax will be bit shifted left by 5 bits and filled with zero:

```
    Before the shift:  ax = 1111 1111 1111 1111 b
     After the shift:  ax = 1111 1111 1110 0000 b
```

In arithmetic terms it means multiplying ax by 2^5=32 because one shift is equal to multiplying by 2.

Also, if you want to learn assembly language, **don't** use HLA. Use [FASM](http://www.flatassembler.net) or [NASM](http://nasm.us/) instead. This way you will get much more help from the community.

Answer (score 1):

well, shift is actually just like multiplication

if you are shifting left 1 time, you are multiplying by 2

which means that:

```
 mov eax, 5
 mov ebx, 2
 mul ebx
```

is the same as:

```
     mov eax, 5
     shl eax, 1
```

Got it?